# Pagination in PHP not working on same page?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I am developing a job portal where i have search box in my index page and for that i tried for pagination but pagination is not working and also if we click number it displaying nothing

i can't figure out the mistakes, results displaying , numbers button, is working perfectly but when click on number  it is displaying nothing Here is my code

```
<?php
    if( $user->is_logged_in() ){ header('Location: /emprdash'); } 
    if( ! empty($_SESSION['uid']))
    {
    header('Location: /emdash'); 
    }
    ?>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form action="" method="post"  >
                    <div id="adv-search" class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" name="term" id="term"  type="text" placeholder="Search for jobs" required />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <div class="btn-group"><button class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" type="submit" value="search"  >Search</button></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        { 
        $limit=1;
        $p=$_GET['p']=="" ? 1:$_GET['p'];
        $start=($p-1)*$limit;
        $status='active';
        $term =  $_POST['term'];     
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM job WHERE status='active' AND  ( jdesc LIKE '%".$term."%' OR  jtitle LIKE '%".$term."%' OR duration  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR budget  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR  keyskills  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR jdate  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR edate  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR cdexmin  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR cdexmax  LIKE '%".$term."%' ) ORDER BY jid DESC LIMIT $start,$limit  "); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $rows = $stmt->rowCount(); 
        ?>
    <?php if($rows>=1){ ?>
    <table class="table  table-responsive  table-inverse table-hover table-striped" >
        <thead>
            <tr class="info">
                <th> JobTitle</th>
                <th>Duration</th>
                <th>Budget</th>
                <th>Key Skills</th>
                <th>Posted Date</th>
                <th>Expiry Date</th>
                <th>Experience Minimum</th>
                <th>Experience Maximum</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $jid=$row['jid'];
                $repl = '<span class="highlight">' . $term . '</span>';
                ?>
            <tr class="success">
                <td>
                    <p><a href="/showjob?jid=<?php echo $row['jid']; ?>"><?php echo ucwords(str_ireplace($term, $repl, $row['jtitle'])); ?></a></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php echo str_ireplace($term, $repl, $row['duration']); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php echo str_ireplace($term, $repl, $row['budget']); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php echo str_ireplace($term, $repl, $row['keyskills']); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php $jdate=strtotime( $row['jdate']);  echo str_ireplace($term, $repl, date('d/M/Y',$jdate)); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php $edate=strtotime( $row['edate']);  echo str_ireplace($term, $repl, date('d/M/Y',$edate)); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php echo str_ireplace($term, $repl,$row['cdexmin']);  ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p><?php echo str_ireplace($term, $repl,$row['cdexmax']); ?></p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="POST" action="">
                        <input type="hidden" name="jid" value="<?php echo $jid; ?>" >
                        <center><button type="submit"  name="apply" class="btn btn-outlined btn-primary" >Login to Apply</button></center>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                }
                 ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php } else {
        echo '<center><div class="well">No results to display</div></center>';} ?>
    <?php
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM job WHERE status='active' AND  ( jdesc LIKE '%".$term."%' OR  jtitle LIKE '%".$term."%' OR duration  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR budget  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR  keyskills  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR jdate  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR edate  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR cdexmin  LIKE '%".$term."%' OR cdexmax  LIKE '%".$term."%' )  "); 
        $stmt->execute();
        $count= $stmt->rowCount(); 
        $countP=(ceil($count/$limit)) + 1;
        $tW=($countP*50) + $countP;
        echo"<center style='overflow-x:auto;margin-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;'>";
        echo"<div style='width:".$tW."px'>";
        for($i=1;$i<$countP;$i++){
        $isC=$i==$_GET['p'] ? "b-green":"";
        echo "<a href='?p=$i'><button class='pgbutton $isC'>$i</button></a>";
        }
        echo"</div>";
        echo"</center>";
        ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['apply'])) 
        {
        $jobid=$_POST['jid'];
        $_SESSION['url'] = "/applyjob?jid=$jobid"; 
        header("Location:/login");
        }
        ?>
<style>
    .pgbutton{
    width:45px;
    margin:0px 5px;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working is because you are clicking a link `<a href='?p=$i'>` to get to the next page. Once you click that link you'll lose your $_POST values because you are no longer submitting a form.

You need to change your implementation maybe change the url on the page and use htaccess rewrite to store the search term in the url. Or store the search term in the session. so you'll always have the search term available.

You might want to put a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />
```

change your page links

```
<a href="" data-pagenumber="2" class="page_link">dsfsdf</a>
```

Then some JS - (please note this uses jquery javascript library)

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('a.page_link').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();

// update page input
$('input[name="page"]').val($(this).data('pagenumber'));

$('input[name="page"]').closest('form').submit();

return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: what solution is better for my above code and how do i achieve this

Comment: Hmmm there are plenty of ways to achieve this. The easiest way that i can see (as i don't know how your site works) would be to add a hidden input to the form with page number. Then add some js for when someone clicks the page number links it updates the hidden input and then submits the form.

Comment: thnks i will try for that , if u are free u may provide the code

Comment: can u modify my code according to that i tried but it is showing same results i am poor in jquery

Comment: @GowrisankarVeluturla can you update your question with the code changes you have made